# Select or update single value using object oriented mysqli concept

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have these two methods which are used to set a flag in my `users` table.
I can see my `setEmailSent` function is working well, but `isEmailSent` always return **0**, even its value is set to **1**.

```
class Mydatabase{
    function connect(){
        ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
        ini_set("error_log","/log/php_error_log");
        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
        error_reporting('1');
        $connect_error = 'Sorry we are experiencing down time.';
        $host = "some.com";
        $username = "username"; 
        $password ='password';

        $db = "loginregister";
        $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db) or die($connect_error);
        return $mysqli;
    }

}
    function isEmailSent($username){

        //**********************************************************************************
        // @Desc -  will check if email already sent to the user
        // @Parms - str username
        // @return - details int
        //**********************************************************************************

            //set up database connection
            $db = new Mydatabase();
            $mysqli = $db->connect();   

            //sql statement
            $sql = "SELECT `emailSent` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?";

            //sql prepare statement
            $stmt= $mysqli->prepare($sql);

            //bind sql params
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

            //sql execute statement
            $stmt->execute();

            //store sql result
            $stmt->store_result();

            //bind sql result
            $stmt->bind_result($emailSent);
            return $emailSent;
    }


    function setEmailSent($userName){

        //**********************************************************************************
        // @Desc -  will set that email already sent to the user
        // @Parms - str username
        //**********************************************************************************

            //set up database connection
            $db = new Mydatabase();
            $mysqli = $db->connect();   

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `emailSent`=? WHERE `username`=?");

            if ($stmt === false) {
              trigger_error($mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
            }

            $stmt->bind_param('is', $emailSent,$userName);

            $emailSent = 1;

            $stmt->execute();
    }
```

Can anyone tell me where I am wrong ???

Comment: you should mention why you downvote ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch data after `bind_result` as

```
$stmt->bind_result($emailSent);
$stmt->fetch();// fetch data
return $emailSent;// then return
```

Read [bind_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)